# ASP.NET WEB API not binding to dynamic object on POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

If have the following Api Controller ... using StrutureMap for the DI ...

```
using System;
using System.Dynamic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using IdentityService.Domain;
using IdentityService.Domain.Contracts;
using IdentityService.Domain.Models;

namespace IdentityService.Controllers
{
    public class AccountController : ApiController
    {
        private readonly IRepository<Client> _clientRepository;
        private readonly IRepository<RelyingParty> _relyingPartyRepository;
        private readonly IRepository<Token> _tokenRepository;

        public AccountController(
            IRepository<Client> clientRepository,
            IRepository<RelyingParty> relyingPartyRepository,
            IRepository<Token> tokenRepository)
        {
            _clientRepository = clientRepository;
            _relyingPartyRepository = relyingPartyRepository;
            _tokenRepository = tokenRepository;
        }

        public HttpResponseMessage Post(
            [FromBody] dynamic data)
        {
            dynamic result = new ExpandoObject();

            try
            {
                var clientAuthenticator = new ClientAuthenticator(
                    _clientRepository,
                    _relyingPartyRepository,
                    _tokenRepository);

                Token token;
                clientAuthenticator.Authenticate(
                    data.Key,
                    data.ChecksumValue,
                    data.Checksum,
                    data.Name,
                    data.Password,
                    out token);

                result.Token = token;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                result.ErrorCode = ex.GetType().ToString();
                result.ErrorMessage = ex.GetBaseException().Message;
            }

            return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, (ExpandoObject)result);
        }
    }
}
```

Using Fiddler, I am make the following post:

```
POST http://localhost:54029/api/account HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:54029
Content-Type: "application/json"
Content-Length: 218

{
    "Key": "7d42276d3c3954716c672543385b575836472f5d543d7776205627413a",
    "ChecksumValue": "127.0.0.1",
    "Checksum": "ao4Ei77BaX1/iMZMTAJxWzt4fxc=",
    "Name": "USER_NAME",
    "Password": "PASSWORD"
}
```

Any idea why my data would be null? I have tried switching to `JObject`, with no success. All the examples I have found makes me think this should work.

Here is the complete response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcY29kZS1tYXR0cnVtYVx0YWxrLWF1dGhlbnRpY2F0aW9uLXNlcnZlclxJZGVudGl0eVNlcnZpY2VcYXBpXGFjY291bnQ=?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 27 May 2013 13:59:45 GMT
Content-Length: 137

{"ErrorCode":"Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException","ErrorMessage":"Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference"}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

**Update**

I tried just a simple example, like:

```
public async Task<dynamic> Post(dynamic data)
{
     var body = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

     return data;
}
```

The parameter `data` is still `null`, but I can see the values in `body`.

Comment: JObject should work.  Dynamic won't.

Comment: Switching to JObject doesn't work either ... same error message.

Comment: Are you setting the content-type header to `application/json` on the client?

Comment: Yes ... updated my question with what else I am sending over ...

Comment: Where exactly does the error occur?  The data property is coming through for me, but your CreateResponse probably won't work because I don't think JSON.NET can serialize an expando.

Comment: I just putting a break in the web api, as I enter the method, data is still null, so when I start to "pick" properties off data, it's null.

Comment: I tried just something simple like 
        `public HttpResponseMessage Post(JObject data)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, data);
        }` and it didn't work ... just seeing what data is passed.

Comment: @DarrelMiller I updated my question with a simple example ... if you could share any insight on it, I would appreciate it.

Comment: As I mentioned before, dynamic will not work.  The serializers don't know what to do with it.  However, JObject does work with your data.  Not sure why it isn't working for you.   Can you show your configuration?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Remove the quotes from "application/json".

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

Comment: I also found had to use JObject as the input type. Then just do `string prop = (string)myJObject["propName"];`

Comment: Won't this cause you to lose XML deserialization as a result?

Comment: The post data is in json format so the content type should reflect that. If the post data was xml data then the content type would be xml.

Answer (score 4):

In an MVC 6 controller (which extends from `Controller` and not `ApiController`) the following does work (with `report` being JSON) :

```
    [HttpPost("[action]")]
    public void RunReport([FromBody]dynamic report)
    {
        ....
    }
```

---

Updated: For MVC 5 this is what I use

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> FBLogin(Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject jObject)
    {
        dynamic data = (dynamic)jObject;

        string accessToken = data.accessToken;
        ...
     }
```

Where the JSON payload is :

```
 '{accessToken: "EAAJF9eVIKOsBABdKVNOLJyfyCnnkrl8mlW2crgZC1NYsDqgq9ZBIZC......" }'
```

Comment: I can't speak for previous MVC versions if this works

Comment: This worked for me.

After that you should the following:
 var email = report.email.ToString();

Answer (score 1):

if you make the param from [FromBody] to dynamic, and if its a JSON object (made with JSON.stringify) then you can just use .ToString() to get the string value and you should be OK

```
   public void Post(string token, [FromBody]dynamic value)
    {
        int userID = db.GetUserIdByToken(token);
        db.InsertJson(userID, value.ToString());
    }
```

other definitions is `headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},`

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. In my case i had success doing this:

Used `dynamic` as parameter type and used `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`.

```
[Route("webhook")]
public class WebhookController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("v1/cobranca")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IStatusCodeHttpResult>> Post([FromBody] dynamic retornoCobranca)
    {
 
        dynamic retornoObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(retornoCobranca.ToString());

        var id = ((JValue)retornoObj.payment.id).Value;
        
        ...
    }
}
```

In my case, the request body is something like this:

```
{
    "payment": {
        "id": "123456"
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

remove `[FromBody]` attribute and it should work

Comment: I tried public `HttpResponseMessage Post(dynamic data)` and it still is showing `data` as `null`.