# Dynamic model binding with ASP.NET WEB API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

According to Scott Hanselman, on his [blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TinyHappyFeatures2ASPNETWebAPIInVisualStudio2012.aspx),  I should be able to do dynamic model binding and return a dynamic.

I have a Web API controller that contains a single method:

```
public dynamic Post(dynamic data)
{
     return data;
}
```

When I make the following call from Fiddler, I am getting a `null` returned.

```
POST http://localhost:57856/api/values HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:57856
Content-Type: "application/json"
Content-Length: 22

{"Name": "jlucpicard"}
```

What am I missing here? Shouldn't it return `JSON` for `data`? This is a simpler follow-up to my original question [ASP.NET WEB API not binding to dynamic object on POST](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16774860/1768).

Comment: Have you tried taking the quotes off application/json?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET WEB API not binding to dynamic object on POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16774860/asp-net-web-api-not-binding-to-dynamic-object-on-post)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your action is returning null because your "data" parameter is not being bound to the incoming json data.

Remove the quotes from "application/json" in your Content-Type header to bind to the data.

```
Content-Type: application/json
```